# VB.Net RAM Windows Type Webcamera UAC

Tags: string, windows, vb.net, types, ram

How can I retrieve the followings:

1. Windows Bit types (32 or 84)
2. RAM value
3. If the pc has a webcamera or not
4. User privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of those require P/Invoke or WMI to determine:

1. Can be surmised using `System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher` (WMI).  Look at "CAPTION" to see if there is 'x64' there.  Some people do some sort of math trick but that seems even more dubious.
2. Doesnt really matter as much as RAM/Virtual RAM **available** but:

   ```
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo.AvailablePhysicalMemory
   Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo.AvailableVirtualMemory
   ```
3. Use PInvoke - `GetRawInputDeviceList`.  Iterate the list and look for HID
4. I dont know how to get the exact level, but here is a way to see if they are admin:

   ```
   Public Function isWindowsAdministrator() As Boolean
       My.User.InitializeWithWindowsUser()
       If My.User.IsAuthenticated Then
       If My.User.IsInRole(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator) Then
           Return True
       End If
   End If
   Return False
   End Function
   ```

There is another way that requires unsage win32 calls